# How do I use ActiveResource with a custom URL scheme?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rest, activeresource

I'm trying to create `ActiveResource` objects for three objects in an internal application.

There are `Tag`s, `Tagging`s, and `Taggable`s:

```
http://tagservice/tags/:tag
http://tagservice/taggings/:id
http://tagservice/taggables/:type/:key
```

`Tag`'s `:tag` is the URL-encoded literal tag text.  `Tagging`'s `:id` is an autoincremented integer.  `Taggable`'s `:type` is a string.  There is no finite set of taggable types -- the service can support tagging anything.  `Taggable`'s `:key` is the ID field that the service for that `Taggable`'s type assigns.  It could be a business value, like an emplyee's username, or simply an autoincremented integer.

If these were `ActiveRecord` objects, I'd code them something like this:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :taggables, :through => :taggings
  def self.find_by_id(id)
    find_by_name(id)
  end
  def to_param
    CGI::escape(self.name)
  end
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :taggable
end

class Taggable < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_mnay :tags, :through => :taggings
  def self.find_by_id(id)
    find_by_type_and_key(*id.split('/'))
  end
  def to_param
    "#{self.type}/#{self.key}"
  end
end
```

Does anyone know what those classes would like like in `ActiveResource`?  Thanks!

Comment: Did my answer help? if so, can you accept it please? :) If not - let me know what you eventually did.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Rails 3.0 ? If that's the case, then you can almost do exactly the same thing in ActiveResource now.

If not, consider trying hyperactive resource:
http://github.com/taryneast/hyperactiveresource

Which I extended to make ActiveResource work almost the same as Active Record.
It supports associations, just like AR - though it does not support "through" - you may have to hand-code that eg for a Baz that has_many :foos, :through => :bars
you'd do:

```
# ugly, but does the job
def foos
  return [] unless bars.present?
  foo_set = []
  self.bars.each {|b| foo_set += b.foos }
  foo_set
end
```